# Como escrever e ler um arquivo .txt em Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, txt

Eu encontrei essa solução no stackoverflow english, porém aparece o erro **unsolved reference em "it", "message" e "context"**

````
import java.io.File

context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
    it.write(message.toByteArray())
}
val file = File(context.filesDir, "myfile.txt")
val contents = file.readText() // Read file```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução interessante que encontrei no site Tutorial Kart, foi que
em kotlin existe um método da classe **File** para criação de arquivos de texto chamado **writeText()**, ele irá criar um arquivo e se já existir ele irá sobrescrever o arquivo, para usar basta apenas instanciar um objeto a classe File e utilizar o método **writeText()**:

```
val arquivo = File("dados-usuario.txt") //nos parênteses passe o nome do arquivo como parâmetro.
    arquivo.writeText("Nome: Luiz\n"+"idade: 10")//aqui você irá passar os dados
```

Prontinho! ao rodar o programa o arquivo será criado. Eu estou usando o Intellij então o arquivo será salvo em .../IdeaProjects/nomedoseuprojeto/arquivo.txt

Agora, para ler o arquivo você irá usar a classe **bufferedReader()** (existe outras maneiras de ler arquivos, mas esse funcionou melhor para mim) e o método **readLines()**, ficará assim:

```
val arquivo = File("dados-usuario.txt")
    arquivo.writeText("Nome: Luiz\n"+"idade: 10")
    val reader = arquivo.bufferedReader()
    val leitura = reader.readLines()
    for(line in leitura){
        println(line)
    }
```

Espero ter ajudado você que chegou até aqui, se quiser saber outros métodos recomendo ler esse tutorial:
https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin/kotlin-create-file/